# How to connect classes that I've written to FXML Controller class

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create an program that will read a list of movies from a text file and display them in a textArea, but whenever I call a toString() function to set the text in the textArea to the list of movies, nothing shows up. Am I creating my MovieCatalog in the right place? Is there a better way to go about this?
I have a Main class and a Controller class for my fxml document that I am creating with scene builder. My movie classes are in a package "movies" which is imported in my controller.

I've created the classes for the movies and a catalog of movies, and tested their functionality in a tester file, so I know the issue isn't with that code. My GUI also works perfectly if I use simple print statements in place of toString().

MainWindowController.java

```
package application;

import movies.*;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class MainWindowController
{
    //Views
    @FXML TextArea movieListArea;

    private Main main;
    private MovieCatalog movieList = new MovieCatalog();

    public void setMain(Main main)
    {
        this.main = main;
        movieList.initializeMovieList("Movies.txt");
    }

    public void shuffleButton()
    {
        movieListArea.setText(movieList.toString());
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;

public class Main extends Application
{
    private Stage mainStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage)
    {
        this.mainStage = mainStage;
        mainWindow();
    }

    public void mainWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("MainWindowView.fxml"));
            AnchorPane pane = loader.load();

            MainWindowController mainWindowController = loader.getController();
            mainWindowController.setMain(this);

            Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

            mainStage.setScene(scene);
            mainStage.setTitle("Movie Program");
            mainStage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If I replace `movieListArea.setText(movieList.toString());` with `movieListArea.setText("Hi");` then "Hi" will output perfectly. I'm guessing something is wrong with the initialization of my catalog. I'm not sure why, though, as the code works perfectly when I run a simple test program in the cmd window.

Comment: There are several things that could cause this issue. We cannot determine this without the code for `MovieCatalog.toString`, `MovieCatalog.initializeMovieList` and without knowing, how/on what object you call `setMain`.

Comment: The issue is likely related to which instance of `MainWindowController` you call `setMain` on. However, as fabian mentions, we need a [mcve] in order to give definitive answers.